# Need values for capacitors and resistors

Tags: capacitor, resistors, battery-operated, fluid-pump

I have experience reading schematics for making guitar pedals, but never designing a project from scratch.

I have a 12V 4A battery powering a cooling element (12V TEC1-12710 Thermoelectric Cooler running between 6-12V,) thermometer (12V) and then a water pump and vacuum pump.

Since I know no math beyond what it takes to code JavaScript, can someone please tell me the capacitors and resistors needed to prevent drawing issues on the pumps, element, and if need be, the thermometer.

[image: Components]

Comment: You need to provide substantially more information. A diagram of how you intend to connect these, datasheet links if available, part numbers regardless, what you are trying to achieve. Qe are not trying to be "difficult" - we need to know tis information to properly answer the question rather than to spend endless time in discussion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I do appreciate it.  Unfortunately I misunderstood the function of the cooling element. While it does cool, it is intended for cooling higher temps to a slightly less high temp.

I was hoping that I could cool above average human body temp to slightly below average body temp. This element produces too much heat that does not dissipate fast enough to accomplish this. It will take graphics card heat and lower it to a slightly cooler temp, but not what I am trying to accomplish. 

In the comments below I did provide the cooling element model number for datasheet,

Comment: If you have any suggestions to make this proof of concept work, I would certainly appreciate it. Have a great fourth.

Answer (score 2):

Just for powering the items you won't need any resistors or capacitors.

Since you haven't provided a schematic diragram of the circuit you are trying to build, I have to assume that your "thermometer" is actually a temperature controlled switch with a relay and a temperature display.  You appear to want to switch on a pump and the thermoelectric cooler depending on the temperature.

In that case, you could wire the pump and the cooler in parallel and have them both switched on at the same time.

---

I wouldn't try wiring all of that through the breadboard.  The contacts are very small and not made for high current.  The cooler can easily draw several amperes, as can the pump.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response so when the cooling element kicks it, it will not draw too much power and disrupt the pumps?

Comment: Actually the pump is running continuously but the element kicks in when the water it pumps reaches a certain temperature. But yeah the relay is what does that

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you don't have a 4A battery, you have a 4Ah battery, which can according to most sites it is on sale can give out only 1A to 2A of current.

The peltier element alone may take up to 10A of current, typically 8A at 12V.

You simply can't connect these devices together without exceeding the rated current of the battery, which can damage it and start a fire.

Limiting the peltier element to 2A which is safe for the battery would require 4V over the peltier, and thus 8V over the resistor. You would waste 16W in resistor to provide 8W of power to peltier.

This can't be done with resistors.

Comment: I have the cooling element run at 6 volts through a voltage regulator

Comment: Which regulator? How are they connected? 6V to peltier would still consume more current than what is safe for battery, from 5 to 8 amps.

Comment: I don't have a picture but it's common voltage regulator with a potentiometer. Okay fair enough is there any way around this

Comment: You need to calculate how much current (or power) each of the loads take, sum them up to see what kind of battery you need to power all the loads. The battery can't provide more than 1-2 amps, which at 12 volts is 12-24 watts.

Comment: Thank you kindly!

Comment: Gona bug you once more, if I canabalize my 12v Ryobi (CB120L) I should be good I imagine. I haven't had time to measure current on each load yet.... but if it runs small circular saws my thinking goes....

Comment: Specifically a 12v 2500mAh 30Wh Ryobi battery

Comment: You still don't have a value how much current you can safely pull from that battery.

Comment: OK! So I just measured current with the MM set at A-DC @ 20 (highest setting, only one that gave me a reading).

Readings are as follows:
Cooling element - .14
Water pump - .03
Vacuum pump - .06
Thermorelay - Negligible 

So, would the Ryobi battery I mentioned earlier function for the total above?
Thank you for your help & patience with me!